# spring-security: modify method response based on a filter method

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I have a REST interface implemented in kotlin and springboot with the following controller method:

```
fun getAllUsers() : ResponseEntity<UserCollectionDto> {
    return getDelegate().getAllUsers();
}
```

The UserCollectionDto is a class that wraps a collection with some additional properties to support pagination.

```
data class UserCollectionDto(
    val offset: Int,
    val limit: Int,
    val total: Int,

    val content: List<UserDto>
) {

}
```

I would like to use spring-security using method level security such that the content field in the response is filtered based on the role of the subject. The role based filtering needs to be done using a function like this:

```
fun filterContentByRole(role: String, userCollectionDto: UserCollectionDto) : UserCollectionDto {
    // Filter userCollectionDto.content filtering by role
    return userCollectionDto
}
```

Is this use case supported by spring method level security? If so, how can it be specified?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Security's [`@PostFilter` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#_filtering_using_prefilter_and_postfilter) on a method that returns a collection, array, map and stream.

This iterates through the returned collection or map and removes any elements for which the supplied expression is false.

For your use case, you would add the `@PostFilter` annotation to the method that populates the `UserCollectionDto` `content`.

Suppose that method is called `getUserDto`.

```kotlin
@PostFilter("@myBean.filterContentByRole('admin', filterObject)")
fun getUserDto(): List<UserDto> {
    // return UserDtos
}
```

In the above expression we are referencing a bean called `myBean` that has the method `filterContentByRole`.

```kotlin
@Bean
fun myBean(): MyBean {
    return MyBean()
}
```

```kotlin
class MyBean {
    fun filterContentByRole(role: String, userDto: UserDto) : Boolean {
        // Filter UserDto filtering by role
    }
}
```

Note that using a bean is optional, if you have a simple filter condition you can simply inline it, for example `@PostFilter("filterObject.someField == 'admin'")`

Don't forget to enable method security `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`.

Be aware that the method that `@PostFilter` is applied to must return a mutable collection.
In the above example, this means that `getUserDto` must return a `MutableList`.

Comment: My response does not return a MutableList but returns a wrapper object UserCollectionDto which contains the MutableList. How can I handle this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi There is no method security annotation for a wrapper object. You can either use the approach above on the method that returns the List (or create a method that returns the List, if you don't already have one), or filter the List programatically (without using a method security annotation).